# Restrict Characters in Android EditText

Tags: android

I have to restrict characters for a particular EditText. For that, I am using
  `android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "` in XML but if I use this I am not able to get **next button** on the soft keyboard in spite of me showing android:imeOptions="actionNext". It is always shows done in soft keyboard. So I removed the digits and I am using  `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` in XML and want to use INPUT FILTERS to restrict the characters programmatically. How do I do that?

Is it possible? if so how to use INPUT FILTERS to restrict only "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
  public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

      if(source.length() > 10) return "";
      else{
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i)) && !Character.isSpaceChar(source.charAt(i))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
      }

      return null;
  }
};
```

Then set it to you editext

```
myEditxt.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Comment: Perfect but max length in XML doesn't work. I had set it for 10. Now I can type more than 10. How to fix that?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this in string.xml

```
<string name="my_regex">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789</string>
```

In XML :

```
 <EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:digits="@string/my_regex"
 />
```